# Downspouts that don't get destroyed by the sun

Tags: gutters

I live in Colorado. The sun here is very strong.

I've purchased the following downspouts (plastic, flexible) to attach to my metal gutters:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Amerimax-Home-Products-Flex-A-Spout-White-Vinyl-Downspout-Extension-85010/100057879

They all get destroyed (crack, break, snap off) within ~year of being attached. Is there a better product/solution that is more resilient to the strong sun of high-altitude colorado?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here. Do you actually need flexible tubing? Under what circumstances do you find yourself moving them? Revise to ask for solutions to your need, not for products that match other products.

Comment: Skilled craftsmen make them out of copper sheet, and some have interesting decorations. Last for years.

Comment: "Is there a better product/solution" Metal ones. Like your gutters.

Comment: Use chains and fishponds.

Answer (score 3):

A splash block will be much more durable than the flexible extension tube. They're commonly made of molded plastic or precast concrete. Some are 100% focused on utility... (photo: homedepot.com)

[image: splash block]

... while "downspout statues" might make a person say "um ok, yeah, that could work too:" (photos: wayfair.com)

[image: gargoyle downspout statue]  [image: fish downspout statue]

You could also just get some aluminum down spout stock and use tin snips or a hack saw to cut to length and adapt it to work with the elbows on the existing spouts. (photo: homedepot.com)

[image: metal extension]

Comment: Wow! My neighbors sure would love to see gargoyles ringing the house...+1 for _style_!

Answer (score 2):

**It's the UV light that degrades the vinyl**, so you either need to protect your current vinyl setup with paint or use some sort of metal downspout system instead.

**For painting**:

Both primer and actual paint should have "flex" or similar additive so it doesn't crack easily when the vinyl expands/contracts/bends slightly.  Automotive bumper paint may work for this.

**For metal**:

Galvanized and "bonderized" (chemically treated for painting so primer is not needed) steel, aluminum, copper and "tin" components should be available (some even at your big box store) to assemble whatever downspout system suits you. Pictured below is an example bonderized steel elbow:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Home Depot also sells simple aluminum elbows, and you can put two together if you need an S shape.  They come in different sizes.  I found it by searching for *aluminum downspout elbow*.  Example:

[image: Downspout elbow made of aluminum]